# Idiomatic Rust code for zipped mutable vector iterator

Tags: vector, iterator, rust, mutable, idioms

I am doing the [Matasano crypto challenge](https://cryptopals.com/) while trying to use Rust (in an idomatic way).

The [second assignment](https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/2) is to xor two vectors. The code I have now is:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;

use rustc_serialize::hex::{FromHex,ToHex};

pub fn fixed_xor(l: &str, r: &str) -> String {
    let mut l = l.from_hex().unwrap();
    let r = r.from_hex().unwrap();
    for i in 0..l.len() {
        l[i] ^= r[i];
    }
    return l.to_hex();
}
```

This works, but it doesn't feel idiomatic code because of the range in the for-loop.

Is it possible to zip `l` and `r` and get a mutable reference to the element from `l` and a non-mutable reference to the element from `r`?

(Note, I don't check the length of the vectors. I know this would blow up in real life, but I would like to focus now on the for loop)

Comment: Questions like this may be better asked at Code Review, but please [read the guide](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) to know how to ask questions there.

Answer (score 5):

You would use the `.zip()` iterator adaptor, for example like this:

```rust
pub fn xor_in_place(l: &mut [u8], r: &[u8]) {
    for (x, y) in l.iter_mut().zip(r) {
        *x ^= *y;
    }
}
```

You could consider generalizing this XOR operation by either

1. Accepting all element types that implement `BitXor`.
2. Accepting generic `IntoIterator` arguments instead of just slices.

Note that `zip` will stop whenever the shorter of the two iterators does.

Comment: Of interest is that `zip` will stop whenever the shorter of the two iterators does, avoiding the possibility of walking off the end.

Comment: Yes, it can be a subtle error. You might want to assert that the slices are of equal length.

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution. I believe it covers all the required cases for Matasano's xor (presuming for single character xor you use a single-byte key vector) and it seems relatively tidy and in keeping with the Rust tutorial.

```
pub fn xor(text: &Vec<u8>, key: &Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8> {
    let key_iter = key.iter().cycle();
    text.iter().zip(key_iter).map(|&a, b)| a ^ b ).collect()
}
```

Comment: You may be interested in posting your full code over at Code Review, but please [read the guide](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) to know how to ask questions there. For example, there's never a reason to take `&Vec<T>` (use `&[T]` instead). Also, theres a non-idiomatic space after `a ^ b`.

Comment: Note that this solution also returns a new vector of the XORed results, but the original mutates in-place. I would use this solution, unless profiling indicated otherwise.